# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\tccSistreinamento\view\modulos\aluno\tmp\listAluno.php on line 10

Tags: php

Preciso de ajuda nesse codigo, nao retorna a lista com o array de campos, ja fiz de tudo, alguem pode ajudar, é pro meu tcc to desesperada, nada funciona

> arquivo *listaluno.php*

```
<?php
extract($_POST);

$genList = json_decode($obj);
echo($genList)


?>
<table class= "table table-striped">
    <tbody> 
        <thead>

        </thead>

        <?php foreach($genList as $aluno){ ?>

        <?php 
        $scampos = $aluno->StrNome. "|".$aluno->NumMatricula. "|" .$aluno->DtNascimento. "|" .$aluno->NumIdUop; 
        ?>

        <tr campos="<?php echo $scampos; ?>">

            <td><?php echo $aluno->StrNome; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aluno->NumMatricula; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aluno->DtNascimento; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aluno->NumIdUop; ?></td>                        
            <td><a href="#" class="editar_aluno"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Editar Aluno"></span></a></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="excluir_aluno"><span class="btTabela glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title="Excluir Aluno"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

erro

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\tccSistreinamento\view\modulos\aluno\tmp\listAluno.php on line 10
```

Comment: Sugiro que retire o seu e-mail da pergunta, esse tipo de coisa atrai todo tipo de spam!
Quanto à sua pergunta, o erro se refere a um loop `foreach` malformado, mas no trecho de código que postou não há nenhum `foreach`. Esse é todo o código do seu `listaluno.php`?

Comment: Posta o foreach completo na pergunta da forma que está não fica claro o erro

Comment: O código que faltava era devido a formatação da publicação... Bem-vinda Aline, o problema não é no `foreach` e sim na hora em que você está enviando o formulário, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/246028/edit) a pergunta e coloque o código do formulário.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente os dados passados no `json_decode` não é uma string no formato JSON valido, logo deve ter ocorrido algum erro ao decodificar e não vai funcionar.

Se a variavel `$obj` é uma string, ela deve conter um formato como:

```
$obj = '{...}';
```

Se veio de um arquivo provavelmente o arquivo lido é invalido ou esta no endereço errado, se `$obj` veio do `extract($_POST);` isso pode ser uma falha no seu formulário HTML, de qualquer forma o problema é o formato do JSON.

E outro detalhe, `echo` não exibe o objeto, só exibe numero e strings ou `__toString`, recomendo que use `var_dump`

### Teste de exemplo que funciona

Suponho que o form deva ficar assim:

```
<form action="listaluno.php" method="POST">
    <textarea name="obj">
    [
        {
            "StrNome": "Nome",
            "NumMatricula": 10000,
            "DtNascimento": "10/10/2001",
            "NumIdUop": 1
        },
        {
            "StrNome": "Foo Bar",
            "NumMatricula": 3000,
            "DtNascimento": "10/10/2002",
            "NumIdUop": 2
        }
    ]
    </textarea>
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

E então tente clicar em <kbd>Enviar</kbd>, deverá funcionar, o teste resultou em:

> [image: browser]

### Erros no JSON

Note que pode ter ocorrido alguma falha no formato do seu JSON, como **uma virgula extra**:

```
[
    {
        "StrNome": "Nome",
        "NumMatricula": 10000,
        "DtNascimento": "10/10/2001",
        "NumIdUop": 1
    },
    {
        "StrNome": "Foo Bar",
        "NumMatricula": 3000,
        "DtNascimento": "10/10/2002",
        "NumIdUop": 2
    }, <-------------------- Virgula extra
]
```

Se houver qualquer falha e fizer isto:

```
<?php

$foo = '[
    {
        "StrNome": "Nome",
        "NumMatricula": 10000,
        "DtNascimento": "10/10/2001",
        "NumIdUop": 1
    },
    {
        "StrNome": "Foo Bar",
        "NumMatricula": 3000,
        "DtNascimento": "10/10/2002",
        "NumIdUop": 2
    },
]';

var_dump(json_decode($foo));
```

Vai retornar isto:

> NULL

### Como *depurar* JSON

Acaso você esteja completamente certa de que o seu json foi no formato correto, então refaça seu script assim:

```
<?php
extract($_POST);

$genList = json_decode($obj);

if (!$genList) {
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo 'A profundidade máxima da pilha foi excedida';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo 'JSON malformado ou inválido';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo 'Erro de caractere de controle, possivelmente codificado incorretamente';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo 'Erro de sintaxe';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo 'Caractere UTF-8 malformado, codificação possivelmente incorreta';
        break;
        default:
            echo 'Erro desconhecido';
        break;
    }
    exit;
}

var_dump($genList);

?>
<table class= "table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <thead>

        </thead>

        <?php foreach($genList as $aluno){ ?>

        <?php
        $scampos = $aluno->StrNome. "|".$aluno->NumMatricula. "|" .$aluno->DtNascimento. "|" .$aluno->NumIdUop;
        ?>

        <tr campos="<?php echo $scampos; ?>">

            <td><?php echo $aluno->StrNome; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aluno->NumMatricula; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aluno->DtNascimento; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aluno->NumIdUop; ?></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="editar_aluno"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Editar Aluno"></span></a></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="excluir_aluno"><span class="btTabela glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title="Excluir Aluno"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

> **Nota:** listei somente alguns erros, no entanto no PHP7 existem mais erros http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php